# Unable to correctly fill array with random data

Tags: verilog, simulation, modelsim

In one of my test benches I created a 2D array filled with random values, as follows:

```
reg [7:0] data [255:0];

initial begin
  for(i = 0; i < 256; i = i + 1)
    data[i] = $urandom%256;
end
```

This construct generates random values correctly:

> data[255] == 8'hAB;
>   (...)
>   data[1] == 8'hC3;
>   data[0] == 8'hDF;

After `data[index]` is used in testbench, I want to modify it's value. For which I am doing as follows:

```
always @(*) begin
  if(/* some condition */)
    data[index] <= $urandom%256;
  else
    data[index] <= data[index];
end
```

It substitute read value in a right way. The problem is, at `t = 0` `data[0]` has unknown logic value (despite being initialize in `initial` block):

> data[255] == 8'hAB;
>   (...)
>   data[1] == 8'hC3;
>   data[0] == **8'hXX**;

It seems to me that assignment from `initial` block is 'ignored', as `data[index] <= data[index];` is assigning `8'hXX` to `data[0]`. All other values are assigned correctly.

How can I resolve this issue?

---

MCVE:

```
module test_tb;

  reg [7:0] data [255:0];
  reg       read = 1'b0;
  reg [7:0] index = 8'h00;
  reg       clk = 1'b1;

  integer i;

  initial begin
    $monitor("DATA %h @ index %d", data[index], index);
    for(i = 0; i < 256; i = i + 1)
      data[i] = $urandom%256;
    forever begin
      #($urandom%5*40) read = ~read;
    end
  end

  always @(posedge clk) begin
    if(read)
      data[index] <= $urandom%256;
    else
      data[index] <= data[index];
  end

  always @(posedge clk) begin
    if(read)
      index <= index + 1'b1;
    else
      index <= index;
  end

  always @(*) begin
    clk <= #20 ~clk;
  end

endmodule
```

I'm using ModelSim-Altera 10.4D to run this test bench.

Comment: You don't need an `else` statement if you want to assign `data[index] <= data[index];` it's obviously. Use just `if(/* some condition */)    data[index] <= $urandom%256;` For the question, you can try to use `reset` or initialization of initial value in the code

Comment: Add your testbench to the post when could see your initial block. Will be better if you post all chain of assignments from` input` to `data[index]`

Comment: I suspect you have a race. We need an MCVE.

Comment: @Roman: I'm aware I don't need to use `else` statement, but I've been tought it should be used as good practice for more complex constructions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a "comment" but can't due to rep, so I'll try to answer.

In your initial block you have a blocking statement, which is fine. In the always@ block you have a non-blocking statement, which maybe isn't what you wanted?. It's possible that due to the if/else condition (which Roman above is alluding to) you have a race which causes the data[index] value to be updated in a way that causes the X.

I would suggest adding in something that halts that branch until you know the initial block is done.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran simulation I saw that everything works well.

[image]

May be something wrong with your simulator? What is the simulator do you use?

Comment: ModelSim-Altera.10.4d.